# Programmatically add views one after another

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am new to Swift (using 4 version).
I have HTML text, that can contain pictures links inside.

```
some text 
<img src=""/>
some text
```

I want to make content scrollable, so I wrapped container (simple UIView) into `UIScrollview`.

Then I parse HTML text into parts: "text" and "image links" into one array (data and type).
Then iterating through that array I watch, if the type is text - I input label with constraints:

If it's the first element of the container, then left, top, right, and bottom are match.
If not, then top matches the previous view's bottom in a container (like chain).

But for some reason, it's not working.
What am I doing wrong?
I put my code:

```
    var lastView = containerView!
    var label : UILabel
    var imageView : UIImageView

    for item in articleContent {
        if (item.type == RenderDetailBlogObject.TYPE_TEXT) {
            label = UILabel()

            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.attributedText = item.data.html2AttributedString
            containerView.addSubview(label)

            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor),
                label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor),
                ])

            if (lastView == containerView) {
                print("ADDING LABEL lastView == containerView")
                label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
            } else {
                  print("ADDING LABEL lastView != containerView")
                 label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
            }

            lastView = label
        } else {
            imageView = UIImageView()

            imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: item.data))
            containerView.addSubview(imageView)

            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

                imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor),
                imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor),
                ])

            if (lastView == containerView) {
                print("ADDING AN IMAGE lastView == containerView")
                 imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
            } else {
                 print("ADDING AN IMAGE lastView != containerView")
                imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
            }

            lastView = imageView
        }

        lastView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
    }
```

EDIT:
Code seems to be right and views are adding correctly, but contraints not letting to scroll view.

I tested constraint (center Y - added 200 more range to it and it started to scroll, but it's hardcoded value, so may be it has more legit solution?)
Without that constraint it's giving error and not working at all.

[image]

Comment: Use `UIWebview` or `WKWebView` to show html

Comment: It's not giving any customisation possibilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this line is your source of trouble:

```
lastView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
```

Right now, when you iterate through items, you constrain each label/imageView to have bottom anchor constrained to bottom of the `containerView`. I would expect that this would cause Unsatisfiable constraints warning (check your console). You want to constrain the bottom of the last label/imageView that you add to the container. Therefore just move that line out of the `for` loop right behind it:

```
var lastView = containerView!
var label : UILabel
var imageView : UIImageView

for item in articleContent {
    if (item.type == RenderDetailBlogObject.TYPE_TEXT) {
        label = UILabel()

        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.attributedText = item.data.html2AttributedString
        containerView.addSubview(label)

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor),
            label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor),
            ])

        if lastView == containerView {
            print("ADDING LABEL lastView == containerView")
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        } else {
              print("ADDING LABEL lastView != containerView")
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        }

        lastView = label
    } else {
        imageView = UIImageView()

        imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: item.data))
        containerView.addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor),
            imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor),
            ])

        if lastView == containerView {
            print("ADDING AN IMAGE lastView == containerView")
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        } else {
            print("ADDING AN IMAGE lastView != containerView")
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        }

        lastView = imageView
    }
}
// Constrain the bottom only for the last view that was added
lastView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
```

If refactoring according to this answer does not solve the scrolling problem, I recommend checking out the constraints between the `containerView` and the `scrollView` - you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48321992/2912282) as a reference.

Comment: "label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0)
is the same as

label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)".

Does this happens because containerView has 0 height in that moment and bottom and top are equals at that time. I thought, that when i add something inside - container's bottom and top will be different. Does it just remembers the point of where bottom (and top) was and even after bottom changed the point will be the same?

Comment: @Vadim oh, I just noticed now that its bottom and top, my mistake.. your previous code was correct, mine is wrong, I will edit the answer ASAP

Comment: @Vadim ok, I fixed the answer.. good that you doubted my code :)

Comment: Thanks) Code is fine now (i edited post a little with changes) and constraint "center Y" not letting me scroll (it automatically scrolls back) :( While without that constraint scroll not working at all.

Comment: @Vadim dont use centerY and centerX for containerView in scrollView.. constrain the left and right anchor of the containerView to the same view as you constrained left and right of the scrollView (but not the scrollView itself), and constrain top and bottom to top and bottom anchor of the scrollView - see this answer for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321859/scroll-a-uiview-in-uiscrollview/48321992#48321992

Although I think in case of x axis, you can also use centerX + width anchor, but definitely not for y axis...

Comment: idk, seems like impossible to fix this..... if i delete CenterY - errors "scrollview need constraints for y position or height"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164072/discussion-between-milan-nosa-and-vadim).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a much cleaner approach would be to use a `UIStackView` inside your scrollview such that you can add any other view as a child view to `UIStackView`. this way you don't have to deal with the constraints yourself.

So your view hierarchy should be similar to something like below.

```
->UIView
    ->UIScrollView
        ->UIView
            ->UIStackView
```

Then add constraints to scrollView as **top-left-bottom-right**

Also add another `UIView` to `UIScrollView` as Wrapper View and add constraint as **top-left-bottom-right** and add two more constraint to this wrapper view **Equals width** and **Equals height** with respect to main view. This will make `UIScrollView` work with dynamic height, more info in this [post](https://medium.com/disblu/scroll-view-auto-layout-in-xcode-8-7f43e82fe33)

Now add constraint to stack view as **top-left-right-bottom** also add a height constraint with an outlet connection.

Now when you add any view to the stack view just change the height constant of `UIStackView` and your `UIScrollView` will expand itself automatically.

Comment: Good point also. But do UIView between Scroll and Stack is really needed?

Comment: Well that depends if you want to have a scrollview with only vertical scroll then having a view in between with a equal width as parent will prevent the scrollview to scroll horizontally, and it also helps to manage the scroll view as there is only single child to deal with also as suggested by many folks in various forums, you can check it out yourself!